# How to restrict fail2ban log file size?

Tags: fail2ban

Sometimes, fail2ban create huge log file in my Centos 7 server.

```
2.9G    fail2ban.log
2.7G    fail2ban.log-20191102
17G     fail2ban.log-20191109
```

Then,I have questions as below:

1.If I delete `fail2ban.log-20191109`,will affect the functioning of fail2ban?

2.how to restrict `fail2ban.log` size?(say no more than 2G)?

Answer (score 2):

Answers first:

1. No, this will have no affect.
2. with `logrotate`.

First of all, your `-2019xxxx` files have no direct connection to fail2ban. They have not even been created by fail2ban in first place.

fail2ban will always append to its logfile `fail2ban.log`. But there should be a logrotate config in `/etc/logrotate.d` for the fail2ban logs.

See the [logrotate man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) on how to configure it (I recommend to read the full man page - logrotate is a great tool ;-) ). Search for `size` and `compress`. Both could help you out. I think a compression would help you best without loosing information, since log files are usually good to compress.

Comment: I add `size 3G
rotate 5
compress`,which means log files will not bigger than 15G